# PHP cURL Constants Undefined Even Though Using Correct Version

Tags: php, curl

I recently upgraded cURL to v7.42.1 because I need to use the constant CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_1 which is only available in versions >= 7.34.0.

http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_SSLVERSION.html

It also requires PHP >= 5.5.19 or 5.6.3.

http://php.net/manual/en/curl.constants.php

I am using PHP v5.5.24.

The correct versions of cURL and PHP are confirmed via the command line:

```
[root@web ~]# php -v
PHP 5.5.24 (cli) (built: Apr 16 2015 06:33:00)

[root@web ~]# curl -V
curl 7.42.1 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.42.1 OpenSSL/1.0.1e zlib/1.2.3 c-ares/1.10.0 libidn/1.30 libssh2/1.5.0
```

The correct versions are also confirmed via phpinfo():

```
Core
PHP Version     5.5.24

curl
cURL support    enabled
cURL Information    7.42.1
Age     3
Features
AsynchDNS   Yes
CharConv    No
Debug   No
GSS-Negotiate   No
IDN     Yes
IPv6    Yes
krb4    No
Largefile   Yes
libz    Yes
NTLM    Yes
SPNEGO  Yes
SSL     Yes
SSPI    No
Protocols   dict, file, ftp, ftps, gopher, http, https, imap, imaps, ldap, ldaps, pop3, pop3s, rtsp, scp, sftp, smb, smbs, smtp, smtps, telnet, tftp
Host    x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu
SSL Version     OpenSSL/1.0.1e
ZLib Version    1.2.3
libSSH Version  libssh2/1.5.0
```

Yet when I try to use CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_1 in a PHP script (via apache or command line), I get the following notice:

```
PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_1 - assumed 'CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_1'
```

The OS is CentOS 6.6. PHP is installed via the remi-php55 repo, and cURL is installed via the city-fan.org repo. I have restarted apache multiple times via both commands:

```
apachectl restart
service httpd restart
```

I have not restarted any other services, or the server itself.

I am at a loss for why the PHP constant CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_1 is undefined. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Please post the php code using curl.

Comment: The PHP code can be as simple as `echo CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_2;`. On my dev machine where it's working it outputs 6 (the constant's value).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those constants are only available when *PHP* has been *recompiled* against the newer libcurl version. They don't appear by just upgrading curl. They're guarded by a [preprocessor directive](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/curl/interface.c#L1200):

```
#if LIBCURL_VERSION_NUM >= 0x072200
```

You'll have to use the numeric equivalent of that constant, which is `5`.

Comment: @mario, thanks. On a related note, do you know if there's a way to recompile PHP so I can still do updates via yum using the remi-php55 repo?

Comment: @Slim Once you compile your own version of anything, you should opt out of packaging updates. The next update would certainly just revert your custom setup.